# Using .vbs to close program on sleep and start on wake up (Windows 10)

Tags: vbscript

I have a problem with Viber for PC application on an HP laptop. Once the computer goes to sleep and is then woken up, the application stops responding.

The workaround I've had before was a .vbs that would close it upon sleep and start it again on wake up. However, I've lost the file and I have no idea how I've done it before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set colMonitoredEvents = GetObject("winmgmts:")._
    ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PowerManagementEvent")
Do
    Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    If strLatestEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
        For Each objItem in colItems
            If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
        Next
    ElseIf strLatestEvent.EventType = 7 Then 
        Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run "calc.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```

This monitors for sleep and kills calculator. And Restarts it on resume.